# Finding extrema of $f(x,y) = e^{-|x|-|y|}(xy-x^2). $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have to discuss local extrema of the following function $$f(x,y) = e^{-|x|-|y|}(xy-x^2). $$

I went through the computation of the raw gradient, to understand when it vanishes but it gets very messy. Can someone help me in computation or show an intelligent trick?

Remember, this is a very basic exercise, please do not use magical guns.

Comment: What did you get for the gradient?

Comment: Things should get easier if you treat the four possible combinations of the signs of $x$ and $y$ separately, thus writing $|x|=\pm x$ and $|y|=\pm y$. You can save some work by noting that $f$ has the symmetry $f(-x,-y)=f(x,y)$, thus reducing the four cases to two. Note that when $x$ or $y$ is zero, $f$ has no gradient, so you need to treat the $x$ and $y$ axes separately. (Take this “no gradient” claim with a grain of salt, though. $x=0$ should be OK, since the second factor vanishes there.)

Comment: Tu hai un dottorato in Categorie, ormai è tardi per mettersi a rivedere esercizi di Analisi 2! :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ci tengo a rimanere giovane.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti: allora ok, fai bene. :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio invecchieremo con le derivate fra i denti.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to study this function on different quadrants. Over the first quadrant ($x,y>0$) we have $f(x,y)=e^{-(x+y)}(xy-x^2)$ and 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = e^{-(x+y)}(x^2-xy-2x+y),\quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = e^{-(x+y)}x(1+x-y) $$
hence $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right)$, lying at the intersection of $y=x+1$ and $x^2-xy-2x+y=0$, is the only stationary point in the first quadrant. You can easily perform the same analysis on the remaining quadrants, then on the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$.